# how to "ease" an input search when the width changes ? ( css3 )

Tags: css, css-transitions, ng-animate

I have an input search that I am trying to get ease with a transition css3 effect.

Every time that the user focus on that input, on the right hand will appear a `Cancel` button which is actually an `icon` to clean the input. Once that icon appears the width of the input changes, I want to ease the movement of that input because as you know the movement or the transition by default is so rough, I have [this JSbin](http://jsbin.com/noponugusi/2/edit?html,css,output) for you to see what I am doing and what I have so far.

the situation begins here

```
    <ion-header-bar>
      <label>
        <input type="text" class="btnCancel"
               placeholder="Sports and leagues finder..."
               ng-model="query"
               ng-focus="isSearchFocused=true"
               ng-blur="isSearchFocused=false">
        <div ng-show="query" ng-click="query=''">
          <i class="ion-close positive"></i>
        </div> -->
      </label>
      <button ng-show="isSearchFocused"
              ng-click="query = ''">
        <i class="ion-close-circled"></i>
      </button>
    </ion-header-bar>
```

css

```
.btnCancel {
  -webkit-transition : all 2s ease;
  transition         : all 2s ease;
}
```

[this is with CodePen just in case](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/YPeyvJ)